# Get as much as possible rows until a given minimum amount is achieved in MySQL

Tags: mysql

For example we have the following Query:

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    order_id,
    product_id,
    qty
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    product_id = 18253
ORDER BY 
    item_id ASC;
```

... and that's the result of it:

```
+---------+----------+------------+------+
| item_id | order_id | product_id | qty  |
+---------+----------+------------+------+
|   15329 |     7369 |      18253 |    3 |
|   15330 |     7370 |      18253 |    1 |
|   15331 |     7371 |      18253 |    7 |
|   15332 |     7372 |      18253 |    1 |
|   15333 |     7373 |      18253 |    1 |
|   15334 |     7377 |      18253 |    1 |
|   15336 |     7379 |      18253 |    2 |
|   15337 |     7380 |      18253 |    1 |
|   15340 |     7383 |      18253 |    1 |
|   15341 |     7384 |      18253 |    1 |
+---------+----------+------------+------+
10 rows in set (0,04 sec)
```

Now I want to get all possible rows (as much as possible) until the sum of `qty` is at least five. Five should be the minimum quantity. Sorted by ascending (item_id).

```
+---------+----------+------------+------+
| item_id | order_id | product_id | qty  |
+---------+----------+------------+------+
|   15329 |     7369 |      18253 |    3 |  // 3
|   15330 |     7370 |      18253 |    1 |  // 4
|   15331 |     7371 |      18253 |    7 |  // 11
+---------+----------+------------+------+
```

So the sum of `qty` above is 3, 4, 11. The third row makes the sum 5 or above so that's all I need.

Another example when I have a quantity of 13 in my inventory:

```
+---------+----------+------------+------+
| item_id | order_id | product_id | qty  |
+---------+----------+------------+------+
|   15329 |     7369 |      18253 |    3 | // 3
|   15330 |     7370 |      18253 |    1 | // 4
|   15331 |     7371 |      18253 |    7 | // 11
|   15332 |     7372 |      18253 |    1 | // 12
|   15333 |     7373 |      18253 |    1 | // 13
+---------+----------+------------+------+
```

How can I do that, is there a possibility?

thanks :)

Comment: @Devon I have clarified the question based on the askers intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate cummulative sum of quantity in the order of increasing item_id and then filter out the result as needed:

```
select *
from (
    select item_id,
        order_id,
        product_id,
        qty,
        @cum_qty := @cum_qty + qty as cum_qty
    from orders, (select @cum_qty := 0) t
    where product_id = 18253
    order by item_id
    ) t
where cum_qty - qty < 5;  -- or 13 or whatever
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/BJBHB12011)

Comment: everyone loves cum quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this can be done by adding the limit clause to your query, like:

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    order_id,
    product_id,
    qty
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    product_id = 18253
ORDER BY 
    item_id ASC;
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: `Unless I'm missing something` unfortunately, yes.